# SQL - Unable to filter table using multiple aggregated function results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm looking for the explanation on why the following code doesn't work. Specifically the line
lc=MIN(lc) OR lc=MAX(lc)
**Isn't this just comparing two numbers?**

```
SELECT city, lc FROM  
    (SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS lc FROM station) AS t1   
GROUP BY city 
HAVING lc=MIN(lc) OR lc=MAX(lc)
```

Edited to remove a lot of the info since people were not reading my question but looking at my code and then providing a fix for it, which I don't need. I want an answer to my question about SQL concept/theory.

Comment: It should return an error -- and would in almost any database other than MySQL.  The use of `lc` in the `HAVING` is improper, because there is no aggregation function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, what do you mean by "because there is no aggregation function"? lc is a number and MIN(lc) also returns a number, am I not comparing two numbers?

Comment: . . No.  You are comparing the `lc` value from an indeterminate row with the overall minimum.

Comment: Hmm... my understanding is that the code is running the HAVING or WHERE for each row thus it is not indeterminate. It would be comparing the current row's lc value with the overall minimum value and if they match then print that row, if not then don't.

Comment: . . The value of `lc` is from an indeterminate row.

Comment: When you do "HAVING/WHERE lc=3" would work despite lc being an indeterminate row. Why can you compare an indeterminate row to a number value but not a number value generated from the MIN function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` to filter your table to a subquery that finds the min and max lengths.

```
SELECT s.city, LENGTH(s.city) AS city_length
FROM station AS s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(LENGTH(city)) AS min_length, MAX(LENGTH(city)) AS max_length
    FROM station
) AS a ON LENGTH(s.city) IN (a.min_length, a.max_length);
```

Of course if there are ties for the min and max lengths you'll get all of those entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS lc FROM station   
WHERE length(city) in (
  SELECT max(length(city)) FROM station
    union  
  SELECT max(length(city)) FROM station
)
```